# Error while updating json column in postgresql with python

Tags: python, postgresql

When trying to update a column of type json in Postgres using psycopg2 the following error occurs:
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'

I am running this code:

```
self.cursor.execute("UPDATE tb_games SET infos_json = %s WHERE id = 10", 
                    (json.dumps({'v1':'a','v2':'b'})))
conexao.commit()
```

The json I'm passing to json.dumps () is valid, I already tested it. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `execute` should be a [sequence, such as a tuple](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14):

```
self.cursor.execute("UPDATE tb_games SET infos_json = %s WHERE id = 10", 
                    (json.dumps({'v1':'a','v2':'b'}),) )
```

Notice that the comma in `(json.dumps({'v1':'a','v2':'b'}),)` makes the expression a tuple (containing one element). Without it, the entire expression in parentheses is evaluated as a string.

```
In [52]: type((json.dumps({'v1':'a','v2':'b'}),))
Out[52]: tuple

In [53]: type((json.dumps({'v1':'a','v2':'b'})))
Out[53]: str
```

---

To make sure that `commit` is called on the connection associated with the cursor `self.cursor`,
it might be better to call

```
self.cursor.connection.commit()
```

instead of

```
conexao.commit()
```

Or, use the [connection as a context manager](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement):

```
with conexao:
    with conexao.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE tb_games SET infos_json = %s WHERE id = 10", 
                        (json.dumps({'v1':'a','v2':'b'}),) )
```

When Python's flow of execution leaves the outer `with`-block, the transaction is committed, unless there was an error in which case the transaction is rolledback. This makes it easier to
consistently enforce the `commit/rollback` behavior without having to write a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: Thank you! With one parameter solved! But now when I pass a second parameter, it gives the same error. I'm trying to run the code below:
self.cursor.execute("UPDATE tb_games set infos_json = %s WHERE id = %s", (json.dumps({'v1':'a','v2':'b'}), id_game))

Comment: That command looks fine to me. You might try `print(self.cursor.mogrify("UPDATE tb_games SET infos_json = %s WHERE id = %s", (json.dumps({'v1':'a','v2':'b'}), id_game)))` to [inspect the SQL](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify) being sent to PostgreSQL.